# In what order is the observable code called?

Tags: rxjs

In the following code, I am having a hard time understanding the order of the chained calls are:

```
 function registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl) {
    return this._adminService.registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl.Url)
      .concatMap(registerId => Observable.interval(5000)
        .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getChange(registerId))
        .takeWhile((info) => info.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC')
      )
  }
  registerDomain.subscribe(res => console.log('res:'+res));
```

I am trying to understand the above code, but I am having hard time understanding the order.  It is easier for me to understand when I see a more simple example like this:

```js
function registerDomain() {
    return register()
      .concatMap(registerId => Rx.Observable.interval(5000)
        .mergeMap(() => 
          getChange(registerId))
        .takeWhile((info) => info === 'PENDING')
      );
  }

  registerDomain().subscribe(x=>console.log(x));



  function register()
  {
  return Rx.Observable.of("registerId");
  }


  function getChange(registerId)
  {
   //at some point this will return INSYNC
    return Rx.Observable.of("PENDING");
  }
```

When I look at this code, the way I read it is:

1. Call register() which returns an observable
2. Merge getChange() and takeWhile into one observable
3. Concatenate the merged result of getChange and TakeWhile with the interval Observable.

   4. Call getChange every 5 seconds until status !== 'PENDING'

Is my above assessment correct?  How do you know when to use merge or concat?

If I wanted to catch errors, for example, register() throws an error, then the it should fail.

Based on @Mark van Straten's answer, some additional questions:

1. So if I want to preserve order, I should use concatMap?  In this case, I want registerDomain to complete before calling getChange?
2. if I don't care about order, then use mergeMap?
3. In the getRegisterStatus method, what exactly is it merging here? Why not use concatMap?

Comment: concatMap is indeed order preserving. The code assumes you want to have the `registerDomain()` complete before start polling for the changes in register. If that is not the case you could merge it together but the `getChange` depends on `registerId` returned from `registerDomain()`. The mergeMap() of getChange is because `adminService.getChange()` will most likely return `Observable<info>` or `Promise<info>` which you need to flatten into the main stream.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three operators for flattening higher-order observables:

- `mergeMap` (aka `flatMap`) - *merge* all streams together, emissions interleave
- `concatMap` - after first stream completes *concat* the next etc
- `switchMap` - abandon first stream, *switch* to next stream when it arrives
  So given the code:

```js
function registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl) {
    return this._adminService.registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl.Url)
      .concatMap(registerId => Observable.interval(5000)
        .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getChange(registerId))
        .takeWhile((info) => info.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC')
      )
  }
  registerDomain.subscribe(res => console.log('res:'+res));
```

We can rewrite this as follows:

```js
function registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl) {
  return this._adminService.registerDomain(caseWebsiteUrl.Url)
    .concatMap(registerId => getRegisterStatus(registerId))
}

function getRegisterStatus(registerId) {
  return Observable.interval(5000)
    .mergeMap(() => this._adminService.getChange(registerId))
    .takeWhile((info) => info.ChangeInfo.Status.Value !== 'INSYNC')
}
```

1. First `_adminService .registerDomain` returns an Observable
2. After it has emitted a value we `concatMap` the second observable returned from `getRegisterStatus`
3. `getRegisterStatus` completes when the retrieved info becomes 'INSYNC', every non-INSYNC emission will be emitted.

I don't think the concatMap is really needed and can be replaced with mergeMap since registerDomain most likely only emits one value

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer so far, I put some additional questions in my post.  I get concatMap better now, but still having a hard time understanding mergeMap, specifically for this case?